# transactional open/write/replace in .NET?

Tags: .net, linux, file, transactions, mono

I am thinking maybe i should restrict it to 8k. I'd like to open a file and write from start to end everytime. However if for some reason (say power outage) it doesnt complete i do not want corrupt data. Is there a way i can do a transactional file open/write/close so it doesnt replace the previous file unless its a success?

When i google i get many results on database transactions and ado instead of files

Comment: NTFS is already transactional by default by virtue of its journal.  Not here, ask at superuser.com

Comment: Hans, the question is about mono on Linux, not normally an NTFS system :)

Comment: Actually i am deving on windows but running it on mono. So...... The question is about .net as a whole

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Write to a temporary file,
2. Delete the old file
3. Rename the remporary file only if the write succeeds.

To prevent data loss if you lose power after step two but before step three, you need one more step:

- At program startup, check for temporary files that have their main files deleted but have not yet been renamed. If you find any, perform step three again for those files.

Comment: Still no. Imagine: write succeeds, delete or rename file to be replaced, power goes out.

Comment: No data is lost but the "system" is in an invalid state.

Comment: @jason as long as i have a way to figure out which temp file is suppose to replace what file i can check if the original exist and if not move the temp file to it (since the original file will always exist until the temp file has been written to completely)

Comment: @Mark Byers: If it needs to be fixed, it's invalid. Personally, I'd use a transactional file manager/system.

Comment: @jason: i need it to work on mono/linux and i dont think there is one on .NET anyways. I prefer a system/lib but i dont think one is available. I think i'll just design it to know if the temp file is complete or not and to be transactional. Of maybe i'll just use a mysql blob and limit the filesize

Comment: @Jason: It's not "invalid". It's a perfectly valid and well-defined state.

Comment: @acidzombie24: Mono on Linux? You should have said that in your question.

Comment: @Jason: ahha, sorry. If it was a regular .NET answer it may work on mono and i'd be happy to accept it. But outside libs i dont trust too much which is why i didnt immediately accept your answer

Comment: @Mark: You probably don't want to keep the File.Delete() step, File.Rename() will overwrite the destination file atomically if it exists.

Comment: @ jstedfast Incorrect `Cannot create a file when that file already exists.`

Answer (score 2):

NTFS in Windows Vista and later is transactional.

I do not believe that you can access it from the pure managed code - you'll need to P/Invoke into Win32 API.

A good place to start would be `CreateTransaction`, `CommitTransaction`, `RollbackTransaction`, `CreateFileTransacted` (and other `*Transacted`) Win32 API functions.

Comment: +1 for an interesting idea, but that method will only work if the underlying file system is transactional. Unfortunately .NET doesn't guarantee that at all.

Comment: @MarkByers Agreed. I clearly stated "NTFS" and "Windows Vista".

Comment: Yes, that's why I reluctantly gave it an upvote. But unfortunately it's not really applicable here since the OP is using Linux. You need to extend your answer.

Comment: @MarkByers OP didn't state "Linux" or "Mono" anywhere in his question. That being said, I now see from other comments that he really needs this on Linux. I'm not familiar whether P/Invoke is available on Linux, whether typical Linux filesystems are transactional or whether transactional APIs of these filesystems are even exposed to the userland programmer, so I'm afraid I can't really help him there.

Answer (score 1):

Slight variation on Mark Byer's solution which I use all the time:

1. Write new contents to a temp file IN THE SAME DIRECTORY as the file you want to replace.
2. If the write is successful, rename[1] it to the desired file.

Rename is atomic so if it succeeds, then the system is not left in an undefined state. If it fails, then, again, the system is still in a pristine state *AND* you have a backup of the content you wanted to replace it with (in the temp file) on system restart.

My typical naming convention is along the lines of:

/path/to/original/content.data

/path/to/original/.#content.data

If the system shuts down somewhere in that process, on restart of your app, you can scan for .#content.data and either present that to the user as what they had been entering when the system went down or use some custom magic to decide whether or not it is "complete" to decide whether or not to rename it over content.data.

I don't know what kind of data you are writing so I can't help you decide what that "magic" would be, but if it's an xml file, for example, you could parse it for correctness and if you don't get an unexpected end-of-file, then you probably have a complete file.

FWIW, restricting yourself to 8k writes isn't going to save you because you are now depending on implementation details in the underlying OS and FS which could change in the next version or be different in a previous version.

Links:

1. http://83.139.107.116:8080/1.1/handlers/monodoc.ashx?link=M%3aMono.Unix.Native.Stdlib.rename(System.String%2cSystem.String)

Comment: The 8k is because i dont need the files big. Its just scrap notes. I mention it bc i was thinking maybe mysql db can suit it if its that small. Woudlnt renaming a temp file to one that exist be an error/exception? i never heard of renaming and replacing the file

Comment: Incorrect `Cannot create a file when that file already exists.`

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that you need to use Mono.Posix to rename files.